# firmware bug bootloader left irq enabled bank 1 irq 9 and boot fails

Tags: pi-2, boot, ubuntu

I updated the packages on my Raspberry Pi 2 (running Ubuntu Mate 20.04) by using `apt update and apt dist-upgrade`. Everything went smoothly. Then I restarted, and got the following error during the boot process:

> ```
> firmware bug bootloader left irq enabled bank 1 irq 9
> ```

Now my pi2 is just stuck there and does not boot.

What would be the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a few years of working with Raspberry Pi, I observed how bad can be force shutting down. And I believe that happened here.

Every time when the electricity goes down, or you force shutdown the device by taking the plug, there is the risk to affect the file system.

Using a UPS to handle the electricity outages and using `sudo shutdown` or the UI controls to turn it off may prevent this problem.

In my case, finally I had to reinstall the OS for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with my Pi Zero board, I compiled a new kernel image and copy to SD card, when it boots up, the screen displays "Firmware Bug: Bootloader left irq enabled bank 1 irq 9", and nothing else displays. Wait a few more seconds, the QT application runs and the Wi-Fi connection also works. So I think this is not a problem for my board. Have you tried just give it few more seconds (maybe minutes)?

Comment: Yes I waited, but then in the end, I reinstalled the system and now it seems to work fine again.